# Unique daterange Index doesn't work (as expected)

Tags: postgresql

I got a simple table bookings:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings 
(
    booking_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    room_id INTEGER NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES rooms(room_id),
    status INTEGER NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES booking_status(status_id),
    booking_period daterange NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO bookings (room_id, status, booking_period) VALUES
    (5, 2, '[2024-04-16, 2024-04-17)'),
    (1, 1, '[2024-04-01, 2024-05-01)');
```

Where `(booking_period, room_id) WHERE status <> 4` must be unique.

I wanted to implement this as an index to find all rooms in a period that are "free" more quickly. (`status = 4` corresponds to canceled)

I have tried using the following unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_myname ON bookings (booking_period DESC, room_id) WHERE status <> 4;
```

to enforce this uniqueness. Unfortunately, postgres does not seem to support daterange 'uniqueness' as expected. (I expected that something like `booking_period_1 && booking_period_2 = true` would violate the uniqueness.

DBFiddle just in case:
[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bLMNxj2D)

EDIT (not for reopening):
Since I am unaware, IF moderators can/will see new comments on closed questions:

It seems that I can solve my problem with an exclusion constraint. Even though this technically creates an index, the sort order (DESC or ASC) cannot be changed. => I need as another index to search the "newest" dateranges first. IF I am wrong with this statement, please correct me. Otherwise, I will delete this question within ~24h."

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look at the linked answers.
If I don't get anywhere with them, I'll get in touch.

Comment: It seems that I can solve my problem with an exclusion constraint. Even though this technically creates an index, the sort order (DESC or ASC) cannot be changed. => I need as another index to search the "newest" dateranges first. IF I am wrong with this statement, please correct me. Otherwise, I will delete this question within ~24h.

Comment: Since i got upvoted and i would loose the reputation if i delete the question, i guess i will leave the question in the "as is" state.